# You use me every day - what am I?

Tags: riddle

After the war seven long years ago

2 men gave me life,

But solemn in peace not in bloody strife

Now 17 years have passed

And my enemies I have surpassed

For I am all around them

4 colors I flash, and 6 letters I splash

Across a great white canvas

What am I?

Comment: Something to do with Kosovo war in 1999? I'll make an attempt at it when I get home

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is:

> Google.

*After the war, 2 men gave me life,*

> It was founded in Sept. 1998, by two men (Larry Page and Sergey Brin). According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_1990%E2%80%932002) the only war that ended in 1998 was a [War in Abkhazia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Abkhazia_%281998%29), it's a bit obscure, but let's go with that!

*In peace not in strife*

> They are a peaceful company, with a peaceful "do no evil" policy.

*Now 17 years have passed, and my enemies I have surpassed*

> At time of posting, they are 17 years old (and 4 months).

*For I am all around them*

> Google is everywhere, in lots of areas, and dominant in its core industry.

*4 colors I flash, and 6 letters I splash*

> Logo has 4 colours, "Google" has 6 letters.

*Across a great white canvas*

> Their home page has always been intentionally left mostly blank white.

Comment: Nice! Spot on answer! How's you figure it out?

Comment: The last two lines gave the idea, then the other clues confirmed it with some... um... googling. However, I've just realised the dates don't add up. Google was founded in 1998, so the 17 years is correct, but subtracting 17 from 2016 I got 1999 and this matched another comment so I found that. Hrm.

Comment: @fi12 I've edited in the answer to correct the above mistake... if you feel this is now wrong, feel free to unaccept it.

Comment: I was actually thinking of the cold war which ended in 91.

Comment: I probably should've clarified in the riddle that the war ended 7 years ago.

Comment: My answer would say that Google somewhat ended the "search engine war" by making all other effort obsolete. https://www.wordstream.com/articles/internet-search-engines-history I know this is now an old question, but I just wanted to say that the Cold War doesn't seem to fit in the question. The "17 years" already place Google in time, why is the war mentioned?
It may be right to say that the search engine war was from 1993 to 2000 or so, but it somewhat violates "After" so I preferred the original phrasing where it wasn't "7 years ago" but just "after".